# Find out my distribution

Tags: linux, centos, debian, redhat

I am doing some work on a Linode and I wanted to know what is the distribution that is being run, so I typed

```
$ cat /proc/version
```

and I got this output:

```
Linux version 3.4.2-linode44 (root@build) (gcc version 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-8) ) #1 SMP Tue Jun 12 15:04:46 EDT 2012
```

So the gcc package used to compile the kernel is Debian. Sounds like the server is running Debian, right? Well, not so much: I then typed

```
$ cat etc *-release
```

And I got

```
CentOS release 6.2 (Final)
CentOS release 6.2 (Final)
CentOS release 6.2 (Final)
```

More specifically, `ls *-release` tells me that the output above comes from the following three files that are in `/etc/`:

1. a `redhat-release` file
2. a `system-release` file
3. a `centos-release` file

And in `/etc/` there is no `debian-version` file.

Does somebody have any idea why the gcc is Debian even though I'm running CentOS?

Comment: I'm new to SuperUser (although I'm a regular user of other StackExchange sites) so I don't know much what are the customs here, but I think that downvoting a question without even leaving a comment to explain why is a bit pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the GCC version used to compile the kernel image, not the one installed on your server. The kernel image was apparently compiled on a Debian machine.

Comment: Fair enough. The kernel has been compiled on a different machine, as per http://superuser.com/questions/244313/compile-linux-kernel-for-different-machine Thanks for the clarification.